# React Native iOS | Linking.openURL ignores other link handlers

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

Linking.openURL ignores other link handlers like onelink - appsflyer, dynamic links - firebase that are called in openURL function from AppDelegate.

for example: we have test.onelink.me, if you simply open it from your phone by tapping on the link, then everything will open correctly, but if you open it with Linking.openURL, it will open the browser and then the appstore.

how to do it right: Linking.openURL should work the same as if a person just tapped on the link

---